# How to debug an issue in the code sum of digit?

Tags: php

I am having an issue in the code

```
Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in /opt/lampp/htdocs/programe/sumDigit.php on line 410
```

Here is the code:

```php
class SumOfDigit{
    public $sum = 0;
    public $num ;
    public function __construct($n) {
        $this->num = $n;        
    }

    public function equation() {
        for($i= 0; $i<strlen($this->num); $i++){
            $this->num[$i] = array_map('intval', str_split($this->num));
            $this->sum +=  $this->num[$i];
            print_r($this->sum);
        }
    }
}

$obj = new SumOfDigit(232);
echo $obj->equation();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the name of your class I assume you want to sum the digits in the value you create an object of the class with. In that case, you can simplify your code by using [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) on the output of [`str_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php):

```
Class SumOfDigit{
    public $sum = 0;
    public $num;

    public function __construct($n){
        $this->num = $n;
    }

    public function equation(){
        $this->sum = array_sum(str_split($this->num));
        return $this->sum;
    }
}

$obj = new SumOfDigit(232);
echo $obj->equation();
```

Output:

```
7
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/2p1MG)

Answer (score 0):

In your code first you assigned a integer to "num"

> $this->num = $n;

and inside the function equation() you are using the same value as array as well

> $this->num[$i] = array_map('intval', str_split($this->num));

Change the name any one of the variable and try.

Hope it helps

Comment: but it still throws an error could you please fix it in the provided code, it will be great help